# Trying to follow the Net::Async::HTTP example to process multiple URLs but failing to get it to work

Tags: perl

Below is what I have. If I change my `$url = @_` to a working URL, it works, but the example is supposed to read in from what's defined in my `@URLs` using the `foreach`, I believe. Could someone show me or tell me why this doesn't work so I can correct it?

```
#!/bin/perl

use IO::Async::Loop;
use Net::Async::HTTP;
use Future::Utils qw(fmap_void);
use URI;

use feature 'say';

use strict;
use warnings;

my @URLs = ( "http://example.com, http://example2.com" );
my $loop   = IO::Async::Loop->new();
my $http = Net::Async::HTTP->new();

$loop->add($http);

my $future = fmap_void {
    my $url = @_;
    $http->GET($url)->on_done(
        sub {
            my $response = shift;
            say $response->content;
        }
      )->on_fail(
        sub {
            my $fail = shift;
            say $fail;
        }
      );
}
foreach => \@URLs;
$loop->await($future);
```

Comment: What exactly are you seeing that makes you think it isn't working? If you're getting an error, please [edit] the exact error text into your question.

Comment: It runs without throwing an error. However, its supposed to be processing the urls from my @URLs and it does not. That's the trouble I'm having with it.

Comment: Is that really the exact code you're using? `"http://example.com, http://example2.com"` is not a valid URL, so I would expect you to get an error.

Comment: I should mention by stating up above that it works by changing the url line, it works only by processing a singular URL, an I want to process thousands from what I have defined in the my @URLs reference.

Comment: I changed it to example. The original URLs did not return any $response codes. If I put a singular URL in the my $url, it ran. But I need it to process what's in my @URLs.

Comment: The problem is the singular URL should be in the @_ where my $url = @_ is, and it is not. Something is broken there or in the foreach, I believe.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. You copied the example wrong. It should be `my ($url) = @_;`. You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot sorry I essentially stole your answer. I read all the comments to make sure this hadn't been said, but I saw it immediately. Did code review the whole day at $work... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the number of items in `@_` to `$url` because that's what arrays do in list context.

```
my ( $url ) = @_;
```

The parenthesis will tell Perl that the left-hand-side of the assignment is a list.

```
(my $url) = @_;
```

This would work as well, but looks stupid.

Comment: AHaha, sorry I missed that. Thanks. that was it.